# Access The Current User Email and Name from the Bash in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, bash

Is it possible to access the current user's name and email address from the command line in OS X? If so, how would it be done?

Comment: I have 4+ email addresses that my mail app checks, which one would you expect to get?

Comment: That said, `dscl . -read /Users/$(whoami)` might have what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an open-source CLI app to interact with Contacts (previously known as Address Book).

### Setup

```
# install CLT, hombrew
brew install contacts
```

### Email of Current User

```
contacts -Hm -f '%e'
```

### Name of Current User

```
contacts -Hm -f '%n'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Awesome tip!

Answer (score 3):

`id -F` will display the full name of the current user.  `id` is a BSD replacement for `whoami`, which will be more portable than using `osascript`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the user's full name using AppleScript. Invoke the `osascript` command from the command line:

```
osascript -e "long user name of (system info)"
```

There's also the `system_profiler` command, which does provides a bunch of information, including this line:

```
User Name: First Last (username)
```

But `system_profiler` is really overkill.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Any idea if you can get an email as well?

Comment: I suppose you could script _Address Book_ re: the current user, but this would launch Address Book whenever the script executes.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to scrape the email accounts from the users' mail preferences (providing they use mail.app) you could do

```
defaults read com.apple.mail|grep -A 1 EmailAddresses|grep @
```

Comment: This might have worked at one point in time, but when I try it in El Capitan with two mail accounts configured, neither show up.